# Making added custom fields in WooComerce product setting pages accessible for compare function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, compare, product

I have added THIS CODE:

```
    // Add custom fields to product shipping tab
    add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_shipping', 'add_custom_shipping_option_to_products');
    function add_custom_shipping_option_to_products(){
        global $product_object;

        $product_id = method_exists( $product_object, 'get_id' ) ? $product_object->get_id() : $product_object->id;

        echo '</div><div class="options_group">'; // New option group

        woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
            'id'          => 'custom_text_field1',
            'label'       => __( 'Weight without Foam', 'woocommerce' ),
            'placeholder' => 'something',
            'desc_tip'    => 'true',
            'description' => __( 'Weight in decimal form.', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value'       => get_post_meta($product_id, '_custom_meta_field1', true),
        ) );

        woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
            'id'          => 'custom_text_field2',
            'label'       => __( 'Volume', 'woocommerce' ),
            'placeholder' => 'something',
            'desc_tip'    => 'true',
            'description' => __( 'Volume in decimal form.', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value'       => get_post_meta($product_id, '_custom_meta_field2', true),
        ) );

        woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
            'id'          => 'custom_text_field3',
            'label'       => __( 'Buoyancy', 'woocommerce' ),
            'placeholder' => 'something',
            'desc_tip'    => 'true',
            'description' => __( 'Buoyancy in decimal form.', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value'       => get_post_meta($product_id, '_custom_meta_field3', true),
        ) );

    }

    // Save the custom fields values as meta data
    add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_custom_shipping_option_to_products' );
    function save_custom_shipping_option_to_products( $post_id ){

        $custom_text_field1 = $_POST['custom_text_field1'];
        if( !empty( $custom_text_field1 ) )
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_custom_meta_field1', esc_attr( $custom_text_field1 ) );

        $custom_text_field2 = $_POST['custom_text_field2'];
        if( !empty( $custom_text_field2 ) )
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_custom_meta_field2', esc_attr( $custom_text_field2 ) );

        $custom_text_field3 = $_POST['custom_text_field3'];
        if( !empty( $custom_text_field3 ) )
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_custom_meta_field3', esc_attr( $custom_text_field3 ) );

    }

// Add variation external "dimentions" fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_shipping','add_variation_options_built_dimensions', 10, 3 );
function add_variation_options_built_dimensions( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ){

    $variation_built_lenght = get_post_meta($variation->ID,"_built_lenght", true );
    if( ! $variation_built_lenght ) $variation_built_lenght = "";

    $variation_built_width = get_post_meta($variation->ID,"_built_width", true );
    if( ! $variation_built_width ) $variation_built_width = "";

    $variation_built_height = get_post_meta($variation->ID,"_built_height", true );
    if( ! $variation_built_height ) $variation_built_height = "";

    ?>
    <p class="form-field dimensions_field">
        <label for="product_built_length"><?php printf( __( 'Ext. dimensions (%s)', 'woocommerce' ), get_option( 'woocommerce_dimension_unit' ) ); ?></label> 

        <span class="wrap">
            <input id="product_built_length" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Built length', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" class="input-text wc_input_decimal" size="6" type="text" name="built_lenght_<?php echo $loop; ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $variation_built_lenght ); ?>" />
            <input placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Built width', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" class="input-text wc_input_decimal" size="6" type="text" name="built_width_<?php echo $loop; ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $variation_built_width ); ?>" />
            <input placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Built height', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" class="input-text wc_input_decimal last" size="6" type="text" name="built_height_<?php echo $loop; ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $variation_built_height ); ?>" />
        </span>
        <?php echo wc_help_tip( __( 'LxWxH in decimal form.', 'woocommerce' ) ); ?>

    </p>
    <?php

}

    //Save variation custom "dimentions" fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation','save_variation_options_built_dimensions', 10 ,2 );
function save_variation_options_built_dimensions( $variation_id, $loop ){

    $built_lenght = $_POST["built_lenght_$loop"];
    if(!empty($built_lenght))
        update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_built_lenght', sanitize_text_field($built_lenght) );

    $built_width = $_POST["built_width_$loop"];
    if(!empty($built_width))
        update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_built_width', sanitize_text_field($built_width) );

    $built_height = $_POST["built_height_$loop"];
    if(!empty($built_height))
        update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_built_height', sanitize_text_field($built_height) );
} `
```

to the back-end of product page in WooCommerce and I need that this new added fields and parameters will be automatically used by compare function. I use YITH WooCommerce Compare plugin to compare products. Now I can use there only Dimensions and weight from bak-end products shipping tab and all attributes, but I need to use there also the new added fields. And if is possible this new data should be in the compare shown as the default woocommerce dimension parameter, which is already shown in the compare table.

The site can be seen [HERE](http://www.grand-tech.eu/2/product/small-case-dc-171305x/).

Thanks.